# use object property as value is incorrect

Tags: stylus

I wanna use color property via itereting object

```
$social-icons = {
    mr: {
        height: 16px
        color: #148de2,
        name: 'mail.ru'
    }
}

.icon
  for $icon, $icon-data in $social-icons
    &_{$icon}:after
      display none
      background $icon-data.color
```

But it crushes on the last string 'background'
What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is example when there is no difference for the parser between nested selectors and hash values if : is omitted.
- and from version 1.0 : won't be optional.

So this ok